# A confusing issue: how to pass a string argument that contain spaces from node.js to python

Tags: python, node.js

I have a app need to get data from a node.js api, and pass the data to python for further analysis.

I use `child_process.exec` to pass the argument, the code is like:

```
child_process.exec('python3 data-output.py ' + `${keyWord}`, function(error, stdout, stderr){...
```

However, the argument `keyWord` is a `string`...when I pass `keyWord = 'A B C D'` the the shell command is like:

```
python3 data-output.py A B C D
```

in python the `sys.argv[1]`can only get `A`

Any good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way. in python change the code like this:

```
node_argv = sys.argv[1: ]

f_name = " ".join(node_argv)
```

It works.

Any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

Pass args as json string then use json.loads() to parse it would be one way. Check the docs for your JS code too. It is common for shell exec calls to accept a list/array of arguments in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

why not just wrap the text / argument in quotes? like:

```
child_process.exec(`python3 data-output.py "${keyWord}"`, ...)
```

which should result in something like:

```
python3 data-output.py "A B C D"
```

Comment: This way already tried. the shell command  is  python3 data-output.py "${keyWord}", cannot pass the value of keyWord.

Comment: what format works on the command line? outside of node